# Async dispose in using block

Tags: c#, async-await

I've got a case where I'd want to dispose an object asynchronously. Since finally-blocks support awaiting Tasks since C# 6, this is possible to do, however I wouldn't be able to handle this with using-blocks, since they only work on (the synchronous) IDisposable.

I reckon there's really no way to get around this, so my question is: Are there any plans to add something like this to the C# language?

Comment: @EliArbel Thanks, I'll try that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already [a proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/114) for that. So far, it doesn't seem to have gained much attention from the Roslyn team, it's also not on [the current roadmap for C# 7.0 or 8.0](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/Language%20Feature%20Status.md).

Comment: Thanks, my sucky searching skills did nothing for me. That's a shame, but yeah, feels like there are a bunch of more important things to address, this is easy enough to work around.